# Inline datepicker beforeshowday won't fire until you change the month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've read several similar questions regarding inline datepicker and `beforeshowday` issues but I've yet to find an exact solution to my particular problem.

I have a function `available` which sets certain dates available but it won't run until you actually change the month.

```
$( function() {

        $( "#whats-on-calendar" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            beforeShowDay: available,
            todayHighlight: true
        });

        var availableDates = ["9-9-2018","14-9-2018","15-9-2018"];

        function available(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
                return [true, "","Available"];
            } else {
                return [false,"","unAvailable"];
            }
        }
    } );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwjxv5ot/4/

I have read in the docs that for setting options after initialization, you need to use the `option()` method.

```
$("#whats-on-calendar").datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', available);
```

But that gives me the same problem. It won't fire until I change the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the method before initializing the datepicker, else it will be undefined.

```js
$( function() {
    var availableDates = ["9-9-2018","14-9-2018","15-9-2018"];
    function available(date)
    {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        return [$.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1]
    }
    $( "#whats-on-calendar" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        beforeShowDay: available,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="whats-on-calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't giving be an undefined error in console so I was none the wiser.

Comment: As per their source, by default it is null. If the function is undefined/null, it will not be called.